# How do you get the Class of an Abstract class (Object) in JavaME?

Tags: java, java-me

I need to get the Class of an object at runtime.

For an non-abstract class I could do something like:

```
public class MyNoneAbstract{
    public static Class MYNONEABSTRACT_CLASS = new MyNoneAbstract().getClass();
```

But for an abstract class this does NOT work (always gives me `Object`)

```
public abstract class MyAbstract{
    public static Class MYABSTRACT_CLASS = MyAbstract.class.getClass();
```

This code will be running in JavaME environments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need

```
MyAbstract.class
```

That expression returns the Class object representing MyAbstract.

Comment: It will on CLDC1.1, but not on CLDC1.0 :: http://blog.javia.org/java-class-literal-on-cldc/

Answer (score 0):

The code you want in the abstract case is:

```
public abstract class MyAbstract{
    public static Class MYABSTRACT_CLASS = MyAbstract.class;
}
```

although I personally wouldn't bother defining the constant and just used MyAbstract.class throughout.

I would have expected the code you wrote to have returned the class 'Class', not the class 'Object'.

Comment: I explained myself poorly. I need to return the Class of a related helper class and the static variable is simply for convenience
Many thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

I think more information is required here.
In Java, an abstract class cannot be instantiated.
That means an Object at runtime cannot have its class be abstract.
It would need to be a subclass that implements all abstract methods.
In JavaME, `Object.getClass()` should be all you need.
Are you somehow trying to reconstitute your class hierarchy at runtime?

In that case, you could implement something like this instead:

```
public String getClassHierarchy() {
    return super.getClassHierarchy() + ".MyAbstract";
}
```